# UEFI not booting OS from USB

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb

So, it all started when I tried to install windows 10.

My computer ran out of battery, I tried to wipe the HDD, win 8 gave me errors after uninstall, I couldnt fix the problems because the wipe erased boot repair things. I wiped everything on the HDD, and installed ubuntu.

Now, when I try to boot from USB and install windows 7 (I changed UEFI settings to Legacy, and turned off secure boot) and it wont work. If I were to describe it, this is how it would go:

I click f12 to go to the boot choose menu where i can choose what to boot the system from. I choose the usb option. Screen goes dark, flashes gray, and returns to the boot choosing menu.

I'm not entirely sure, but I think I might have chosen the MBR partition from Rufus while installing the bootable ISO on my usb. could this be the problem?

Also, should I just get 8.1 again and not worry about Windows 7? I prefer 7 over the whole new 8.1 live tiles thing, but that might be a biased opinion. I also want to hear what you guys think.

Comment: Why did you enable Legacy boot if Windows 7 supports UEFI?

Comment: Either way, it's the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepare a windows 10 installer usb using rufus (having previously downloaded the .iso eg by using "media creation tool").  This method supports instaling windows 10 either by EFI method, or old bios method - you choose which by pressing f12 at boot up and choosing your USB disk which should appear twice (one with its name preceded EFI, one not)

If you use rufus to add a windows 7 .iso, it will also add the required EFI/ files to the installer (not there by default), so you can then install it in EFI mode.  Presumably you then have the same choice of install type as I've outlined in previous paragraph.

I have all my o/s loaded in EFI mode so I can back up the EFI partition as well as the o/s, meaning I can restore an entirely working system from backup (unlike the bad old days of MBR).  EFI is the way to go.

Pingers.

EDIT: In rufus, you *must* select **GPT** and make sure **FAT32** is the file system

Comment: oh in rufus, you must select GPT and make sure FAT32 is the file system

Comment: Well, that worked! GPT and FAT32! This worked with Windows 8, but I havent tried it with 7.

Comment: It will work provided it is 64-bit since you are using 64-bit hardware.